# Splitting up an array into a hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-hash

I have an array of about 860 items, I would like to turn it into a hash, the array structure is (Key1, value 1, value2, value 3, Key2, value 1, value 2, value 3........... etc etc) except in real life it looks like (Peter, 150, 39, 345, John, 123, 450, 402, Mary, 145, 345, 506............). Original these are four arrays which I have transposed together, so I could reach the same end goal by starting from 4 independent arrays.

I would like

```
Hash {Peter=> [150, 39, 345], John=>[123,450,402], Mary => [145,345,506] etc etc
```

I feel there should be a nice neat way to do this, but it eludes me, possibly because I don't know enough ruby.

Comment: If the value arrays are all the same length couldn't you just iterate and add each item to the appropriate hash entry? You don't really state what the original arrays are, but it seems like it'd be easier to just skip the array concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the data is always in sets of 4:

```
l = ['Peter', 150, 39, 345, 'John', 123, 450, 402, 'Mary', 145, 345, 506]
h = {}
l.each_slice(4).each do |chunk|
    h[chunk[0]] = chunk[1..chunk.length]
end
```

Alternately, if you know the keys are always strings:

```
l = ['Peter', 150, 39, 345, 'John', 123, 450, 402, 'Mary', 145, 345, 506]
h = {}
current_key = ""
l.each do |item|
    if item.is_a? String
        current_key = item
        h[item] = []
    else 
        h[current_key] << item 
    end 
end
```

Basically, you need to work out how to slice the array appropriately and then loop through.

Also if you've already got them as separate arrays you could easily just:

```
array_1 = ['Peter', 150, 39, 345]
array_2 = ['John', 123, 450, 402]
array_3 = ['Mary', 145, 345, 506]
h = {}    

[array_1,array_2, array_3].each do |a|
    h[a[0]] = a[1:a.length]
end

# One line version:
[array_1,array_2, array_3].map{|a| h[a[0]] = a[1..a.length]}
```

Which I'd argue is the cleanest method.

Answer (score 4):

One more way:

```
l = ['Peter', 150, 39, 345, 'John', 123, 450, 402, 'Mary', 145, 345, 506]

Hash[*l.each_slice(4).flat_map { |a, *b| [a, b] }]
#=> {"Peter"=>[150, 39, 345], 
#    "John" =>[123, 450, 402], 
#    "Mary" =>[145, 345, 506]}
```

If you already have arrays, solution will be even more simple:

```
arrays = [array_1, array_2, array_3]
Hash[*arrays.flat_map {|a, *b| [a, b]} ]
#=> {"Peter"=>[150, 39, 345], "John"=>[123, 450, 402], "Mary"=>[145, 345, 506]}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
arr = ['Peter', 150, 39, 345, 'John', 123, 450, 'Mary', 145, 345, 506, 222]

arr.slice_before {|a| String === a }.
    each_with_object({}) {|(f,*rest), h| h[f] = rest}
  #=> {"Peter"=>[150, 39, 345], "John"=>[123, 450], "Mary"=>[145, 345, 506, 222]}
```

[Enumerable#slice_before](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) made its debut in Ruby v2.3. One could alternatively use [Enumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when), which was new in v2.2.

Here's are a couple more ways that work with earlier versions of Ruby.

```
arr.chunk { |e| String === e }.
    each_slice(2).
    with_object({}) { |((_,(k)),(_,v)), h| h[k] = v }
```

and

```
a = []
enum = arr.to_enum
loop do
  o = enum.next
  (String === o) ? a << [o,[]] : a.last.last << o
end
Hash[a]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Original these are four arrays which I have transposed together, so I could reach the same end goal by starting from 4 independent arrays.

I assume you have something like this to start with:

```
a = ["Peter", "John", "Mary"]
b = [150, 123, 145]
c = [39, 450, 345]
d = [345, 402, 506]
```

You can combine the "value" arrays via `zip`:

```
values = b.zip(c, d)
#=> [[150, 39, 345], [123, 450, 402], [145, 345, 506]]
```

And add the "key" array via another `zip`:

```
a.zip(values)
#=> [["Peter", [150, 39, 345]], ["John", [123, 450, 402]], ["Mary", [145, 345, 506]]]
```

This is already the correct structure, so we can just call `to_h`:

```
a.zip(values).to_h
#=> {"Peter"=>[150, 39, 345], "John"=>[123, 450, 402], "Mary"=>[145, 345, 506]}
```

Of course you don't need the intermediate variable, `a.zip(b.zip(c, d)).to_h` returns the same result.

Comment: Or you can `transpose` instead of the second `zip`: `Hash[a.zip([b, c, d].transpose)]`

Comment: ...or `[a,b,c,d].transpose.each_with_object({}) { |(k,*v),h| h[k]=v }`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
l = ['Peter', 150, 39, 345, 'John', 123, 450, 402, 'Mary', 145, 345, 506]

l.each_slice(4).to_a.inject({}){|acc, temp| acc[temp.first]=temp.last(3); acc}

#=>{"Peter"=>[150, 39, 345], "John"=>[123, 450, 402], "Mary"=>[145, 345, 506]}
```